# ChartJS: Grouped Stacked Bar Chart not Grouping

Tags: javascript, html, graph, chart.js

I am trying to create a grouped, stacked bar chart in ChartJS. For the below code, all works fine apart from the grouping aspect, it simply stacks all datasets on top of one another.

```
stackedBarChartData = {
        barPercentage: 1.0,
        //labels: stackedBarData['skills'],
        labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
        datasets:[
            {
              label: 'Dataset 1',
              data: [0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 9],
              backgroundColor: '#D6E9C6',
              stack: 'Stack 0',
            },
            {
              label: 'Dataset 2',
              data: [0, 12, 3, 6, 2, 4, 8, 9],
              backgroundColor: '#FAEBCC',
              stack: 'Stack 0',
            },
            {
              label: 'Dataset 3',
              data: [0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 9],
              backgroundColor: '#EBCCD1',
              stack: 'Stack 1',
            },
        ]
    }
groupedChartOptions = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: stackedBarChartData,
    options: {
        scales: {
            scaleShowValues: true,
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: options.xLabel
                },
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip: false
                },
                gridLines: { display: false }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: options.yLabel
                },
                gridLines: { display: false }
            }]
        },
        title:{
            display: true,
            text: options.title
        }
    }
}
return new Chart(chartObject, chartOptions);
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config you are using should work, the reason it not working is likely to be your verry outdated version of Chart.js. I suspect you are still using version `2.4.0`. If you upgrade to 2.9.4 it will work

https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/6h2ey8mu/8/

Answer (score 3):

Your definition uses Chart.js v2 syntax and it seems to work fine if you use the latest version of Chart.js v2 (2.9.4) as shown below.

```js
const stackedBarChartData = {
  barPercentage: 1.0,
  //labels: stackedBarData['skills'],
  labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
  datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: [0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 9],
      backgroundColor: '#D6E9C6',
      stack: 'Stack 0',
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: [0, 12, 3, 6, 2, 4, 8, 9],
      backgroundColor: '#FAEBCC',
      stack: 'Stack 0',
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 3',
      data: [0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 9],
      backgroundColor: '#EBCCD1',
      stack: 'Stack 1',
    },
  ]
};
const groupedChartOptions = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: stackedBarChartData,
  options: {
    scales: {
      scaleShowValues: true,
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'A'
        },
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'B'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }]
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'XYZ'
    }
  }
};
new Chart('myChart', groupedChartOptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="120"></canvas>
```